# Non-extendable 3D TQFTs

Tags: ct.category-theory, differential-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, quantum-topology

Non-extendable 2D TQFTs correspond to finite dimensional Frobenius algebras [1].

How about 3D TQFTs? While the answer is clear for the extended ones (e.g. (3,2,1) TQFTs almost correspond to modular tensor categories [2]), I have not seen any discussion for (3,2) TQFTs.

More precisely, can one classify the functors

$$Cob_{3,2}^{oriented} \to (Vect_\mathbb{C})?$$

**Reference**

- [1] [Cohomology rings and 2D TQFTs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8772/cohomology-rings-and-2d-tqfts)
- [2] K. Walker's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386/do-all-3d-tqfts-come-from-reshetikhin-turaev/)
- [3] related - [Example of a non-extendable TQFT?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290880/example-of-a-non-extendable-tqft)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out Andras Juhasz' paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.0668.pdf

Specifically, Theorem 1.10:

> There is an equivalence between the symmetric monoidal category
> of (2+1)-dimensional TQFTs and the category of J-Algebras.

J-Algebras are somewhat cumbersome to define.
They are graded vector spaces equipped with a Frobenius-like structure, together with an action of the genus $g$ mapping class group on the $g$-th graded piece.